# Testing for whether an object is an angularJS $resource

Tags: angularjs

Simple (seeming) question - I'm trying to do a simple sanity check in my AngularJS controller to make sure that my $resource is actually instantiated as such. It's a largish app, but for example:

```
.factory('AccountSearchService_XHR', ["$resource", function($resource) {
  var baseUrl = "http://localhost\\:8081/api/:version/accounts/:accountNumber";
  return $resource(baseUrl,
              {
                version: "@version",
                accountNumber: "@accountNumber"
              },
              {
                get: {method: 'GET', isArray: false}
              });
}]);
```

Then later, in controller:

```
$scope.accountObj.currentAccount = AccountSearchService_XHR.get({
                                    version:        "v1",
                                    accountNumber:  "1234"
                                  },
                                  function(result) {... etc etc});
```

The call to my API works fine, everything returns data like I expect - but I'd like to test to see if `$scope.accountObj.currentAccount` is a Resource before trying to make the `.get` call (notice the super important capital "R").

When I inspect the object `$scope.accountObj.currentAccount` in chrome debugger, it looks like:

```
Resource {accountHolderName: Object, socialSecurityNumer: null, birthDate: "05/14/1965", maritalStatus: ...}
```

Because of some complexity in my setup though, occasionally it gets overwritten as a normal object (`typeof` returns `"object"`), but inspecting it in debugger confirms it lost its `Resource` status.

So - does anyone know of a way to test whether it is a $resource? Almost like `typeof $scope.accountObj.currentAccount` returns `"Resource"`? Or perhaps a better best practices way to ensure that things are connecting up all proper and respectable-like?

All the SO articles I have seen when searching revolve around actual Jasmine testing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not trying to be flippant, but why are you worried about being in a situation where the dependency injector isn't giving you an ngResource?

Comment: @DavidSouther The app has several sections of the screen all managed by different controllers. I wanted to create a Service that would pass $resource objects around to different controllers. It works, but occasionally a controller's $scope calls the Service before the Service has instantiated that particular $resource. Hence, a simple test to help me track down when/where it happens.

Comment: I think you'll find the app is saner to manage if you wrap access to the resource with the service itself. You will reduce your dependencies, as well - instead of having to know about Resources *and* Services *and* application load order, the Service will handle Resources and loading, and the controllers can receive $qs directly from the service.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check it via `instanceof yourVariable === "Resource"`.  Because Resource is an object the type will always return as an Object, but if you check that it's an instance of the Resource "class" that should work just fine.

Comment: I think you mean something more along the lines of `instanceof yourVariable === ngResource`, except ngResource is dependency injected, and tengen will always get the same DId service whether it's the ngResource he wants or not.

Comment: @DavidSouther true, but he doesn't ask if he wants to check if it is that specific resource or not, just if it is a resource.

Comment: @claydiffrient You are correct, that's what I want. I'll mark this as correct, because I believe it will probably work once I fiddle with it enough. The trick seems to be getting  Resource/ngResource/$resource in $scope where I need to do the test. I can inject $resource, but `$scope.demographicsHolder instanceof $resource'` returns `false`, even when I would expect `true`. Not certain how to get ngResource or Resource (if it exists) in scope for the test. Thanks for the help, both of you - appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

@tengen you need to have injected the type you want to check against, instead of $resource.

All resources are instances of the "class" "Resource", but that's a function that's defined inside of the factory method of the $resource service, so you have no outside visibility to use it with the instanceof operator.

However, you're wrapping that $resource creating with your own custom type, AccountSearchService_XHR, and that's what you need to make the check against.

You need AccountSearchService_XHR to be injected in your code and then perform myRef instanceof AccountSearchService_XHR and that will be === true.

Answer (score 0):

Digging up an old question my intern just had. The simple solution is:

```
if ($scope.accountObj.currentAccount instanceof AccountSearchService_XHR)
   return 'This is a AccountSearchService_XHR Resource';
else
   return 'This is not a AccountSearchService_XHR Resource';
```

which with proper names (`Users` being a `$resource`) and real case scenario should lead you to write something like this:

```
if (!(this.user instanceof Users))
    this.user = new Users(this.user);

this.user.$update();
```